# How to create BigQuery Data Transfer Service using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-bigquery

I tried creating a Data Transfer Service using bigquery_datatransfer. I used the following python library,

> pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer

Used the method

> create_transfer_config(parent, transfer_config)

I have defined the transfer_config values for the **data_source_id: amazon_s3**

```
transfer_config = {
    "destination_dataset_id": "My Dataset",
    "display_name": "test_bqdts",
    "data_source_id": "amazon_s3",
    "params": {
        "destination_table_name_template":"destination_table_name",
        "data_path": <data_path>,
        "access_key_id": args.access_key_id,
        "secret_access_key": args.secret_access_key,
        "file_format": <>
    },
    "schedule": "every 10 minutes"
}
```

But while running the script I'm getting the following error,

```
ValueError: Protocol message Struct has no "destination_table_name_template" field.
```

The fields given inside the params are not recognized. Also, I couldn't find what are the fields to be defined inside the "params" **struct**

What are the fields to be defined inside the "params" of transfer_config to create the Data Transfer job successfully?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_scheduled_query), you should try putting your code inside the `google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict()` function.

```
transfer_config = google.protobuf.json_format.ParseDict(
    {
        "destination_dataset_id": dataset_id,
        "display_name": "Your Scheduled Query Name",
        "data_source_id": "scheduled_query",
        "params": {
            "query": query_string,
            "destination_table_name_template": "your_table_{run_date}",
            "write_disposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            "partitioning_field": "",
        },
        "schedule": "every 24 hours",
    },
    bigquery_datatransfer_v1.types.TransferConfig(),
)
```

Please let me know if it helps you